# Can't create a new mime type on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, xfce

i want to create a new mime type for idx/sub subtitles. The current mime type is 'text/plain'. I created a file idx.xml in /usr/share/mime/packages with this content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
  <mime-type type="video/x-idx">
    <comment xml:lang="en">idx</comment>
    <icon name="bdsup2sub"/>
    <glob pattern="*.idx"/>
  </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

and updated the mime database with

```
sudo updata-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```

A new xml file is created in /usr/share/mime/video with the name 'x-idx.xml'. The content is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mime-type xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info" type="video/x-idx">
  <!--Created automatically by update-mime-database. DO NOT EDIT!-->
  <comment xml:lang="en">idx</comment>
  <icon name="bdsup2sub"/>
  <glob pattern="*.idx"/>
</mime-type>
```

There is also the new mime type in the Xfce Mime Type editor. But when i check the idx file again the mime type is still

```
text/plain
```

Rebooting the computer doesn't change anything. What else can i do? Do i need to do anything with that 'magic number' that can be used to detect a mime type?

Comment: You can take a look here : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37927_01/html/E36692/glvax.html. Sorry it's in french but you can find , I think, the same in english. What they say ? Never modify xml files installed by applications in <MIME>/packages. Modify rather Overrides.xml ...I let you read the doc. Good luck. Eventually you can ask here for xfce : https://forum.xfce.org/index.php

Comment: Thats my Problem. Adding New XML files in the specific folder in home dir doesnt work.